# Suscription and subject for form changes

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs5, angular5

I'm creating a form with some inputs I want to control, for example, I have an email input.

I'm creating an observable to check if users wrote has email format:

```
//html:
<input matInput type="email" ngModel (ngModelChange)="emailChanged$.next($event)" name="email" required placeholder="EMAIL"/>

//ts:
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {

   emailValid$: Observable<boolean>;
   emailChanged$: Subject<string>;
   subscription: Subscription;


   constructor() {


      this.emailChanged$ = new Subject<string>();

      this.subscription = this.emailChanged$
       .debounceTime(500)
       .map(this.isValidEmail)
       .subscribe(isValid => this.emailValid$ = isValid)

   }

   isValidEmail(email: string): Observable<boolean>{
       return Observable.of(/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/.test(email));
   }
```

But it's not correct, I have this error when executing (and debounceTime expires)

```
TypeError: Observable_1.Observable.of is not a function
  at MapSubscriber.MyComponent.isValidEmail [as project] (my-component.component.ts:73)
  at MapSubscriber._next (map.js:79)
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: Did you import it with `import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';`?

Comment: oh! no I didn't it was the mistake, thanks!

Comment: why you not used pattern attribute?

Comment: because pattern can be improved with Subjects

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Import `of` from the

```
import { of } 'rxjx/observables/of'
```

and use it without Observable, just `of`.

```
isValidEmail(email: string): Observable<boolean>{
    return of(/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/.test(email));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

just use `pattern` attributes

```
<input matInput type="email" ngModel pattern="^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$" name="email" required placeholder="EMAIL"/>
```

No need to write extra code

Comment: Thanks, but I prefer use Subject, because it can be improved with its functionallity as debounceTime for example